# snowflake convert elements in an array with double quotes to single quotes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to do arrays overlap as below where ["a", "b", "c" ] is coming from a string object. How do I convert ["a", "b", "c" ] to ['a', 'b', 'c' ]?

```
SELECT ARRAYS_OVERLAP(['a'],["a", "b", "c" ]);
```

Comment: Please provide actual table defintion. If you store data as string then `SELECT ARRAYS_OVERLAP(['a'],PARSE_JSON('["a", "b", "c" ]'));`